# MSTest Custom TestInitialize per test

Tags: mstest

I have a `TestClass` with many `TestMethod` methods in it. There is a `ClassInitialize` method which sets up the common environment that all tests require.

However, some tests need to run inside a transaction that rolls back , and some don't

Is there a way to decorate those few tests with a special attribute that MSTest picks up and sets up a `TransactionScope` before running and rolls back afterwards?

Or, is there a way inside the `TestInitialize` method to tell which test method is running, and to manually check if that method has a custom attribute on it and if so manually set up the `TransactionScope`? The equivalent would have to be coded into the `TestCleanup` method.

I'd rather not split these tests that require a tx rollback into a separate `TestClass`, because I only want one `ClassInitialise` method to set the environment up, and it is expensive to run. I can't guarantee which `TestClass` will get executed before the other `TestClass` (they may even get distributed across separate test agents).

As a fallback, I know that I could get every `TestMethod` to run inside a tx that rolls back, but I was just wondering if what I'm asking for is possible.

Comment: AFAIK what you are asking for is not possible

Comment: Split them into separate classes and use the singleton pattern to do the class initialization, so the first one in initializes and the second one just uses whatever the first one setup.